# Why does @RestResource(exported=false) on delete(entity) affect deleteById and not vice versa?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a good old spring data rest repository configured to block DELETE operation from REST API like so. The intention is to provide exhaustive declaration of security rules for the rest API:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel ....)
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<...> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasPermission( ... )")
    void deleteById(Long id);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(SomeEntity entity);

    ...
}
```

Calling `DELETE someEntity/{id}` results in "405 Method Not Allowed", although I'd expect the first method (deleteById) to be invoked and go through; not the second one (delete).

Switching the `@RestResource(exported = false)` around i.e. placing it on `deleteById()` doesn't seem to have any effect (HTTP `DELETE someEntity/{id}` goes through).

Q1: Perhaps there is some functional reason behind this, but semantically it doesn't add up. Why?

Q2: How does Spring add the relevant interceptors to `delete()`, since the `SimpleJpaRepository.delete()` method is only called from `deleteById()` (therefore no proxying takes place)?

*Q3: Are there any exceptions to the rule? (And why?)*

---

**Update 1:** Apparently there are some idiosyncrasies with `@PreAuthorize` as well - plain `hasRole` doesn't seem to be effective when only used with `deleteById()`, but `hasPermission()` is. The official documentation shows the annotation used with both delete methods without further explanation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

---

Versions: Spring-data-rest 3.1.10.RELEASE (via spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE)